# How to query date range in mongo, where field itself is a date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, range-query

I have a JSON document stored in mongodb where a sub-document is date-time-stamp. I need to query and filter sub-documents between a date range.

I am using mongo shell to play around with the query.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5d9bf09c242af456ff5dd149"),
    "configId": "c2",
    "name": "ajit test",
    "description": "this is test desc",
    "confidence": 0,
    "report": {
        "2019-10-05T02:12:44Z": [
            {
                "VariantId": "1",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "2.1",
                    "high": "4.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId": "2",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "4.5",
                    "high": "4.7"
                }
            }
        ],
        "2019-10-06T02:12:44Z": [
            {
                "VariantId": "1",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "2.1",
                    "high": "4.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId": "2",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "4.5",
                    "high": "4.7"
                }
            }
        ],
        "2019-10-08T02:12:44Z": [
            {
                "VariantId": "1",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "3.5",
                    "high": "6.7"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId": "2",
                "bestProbability": "3.2",
                "hdi": {
                    "low": "3.5",
                    "high": "6.7"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

I looking for a query that must return a sub-set of embedded documents between dates 2019-10-06T02:12:44Z and 2019-10-08T02:12:44Z only.

Comment: can you post your sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert the sub-document `report` into an array of key-value pairs where the key would represent the date. Later, that array has to be filtered and converted back to an object again.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "report":{
                $objectToArray:"$report"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "report":{
                $filter:{
                    "input":"$report",
                    "as":"doc",
                    "cond":{
                        $and:[
                            {
                                $gte:["$$doc.k","2019-10-06T02:12:44Z"]
                            },
                            {
                                $lte:["$$doc.k","2019-10-08T02:12:44Z"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "report":{
                $arrayToObject:"$report"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9c15312cb9ef5d628ea95d"),
    "configId" : "c2",
    "name" : "ajit test",
    "description" : "this is test desc",
    "confidence" : 0,
    "report" : {
        "2019-10-05T02:12:44Z" : [
            {
                "VariantId" : "1",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "2.1",
                    "high" : "4.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId" : "2",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "4.5",
                    "high" : "4.7"
                }
            }
        ],
        "2019-10-06T02:12:44Z" : [
            {
                "VariantId" : "1",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "2.1",
                    "high" : "4.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId" : "2",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "4.5",
                    "high" : "4.7"
                }
            }
        ],
        "2019-10-08T02:12:44Z" : [
            {
                "VariantId" : "1",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "3.5",
                    "high" : "6.7"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId" : "2",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "3.5",
                    "high" : "6.7"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9c15312cb9ef5d628ea95d"),
    "configId" : "c2",
    "name" : "ajit test",
    "description" : "this is test desc",
    "confidence" : 0,
    "report" : {
        "2019-10-06T02:12:44Z" : [
            {
                "VariantId" : "1",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "2.1",
                    "high" : "4.0"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId" : "2",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "4.5",
                    "high" : "4.7"
                }
            }
        ],
        "2019-10-08T02:12:44Z" : [
            {
                "VariantId" : "1",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "3.5",
                    "high" : "6.7"
                }
            },
            {
                "VariantId" : "2",
                "bestProbability" : "3.2",
                "hdi" : {
                    "low" : "3.5",
                    "high" : "6.7"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```